# Best graphical option for designing a Python game with static images?

Tags: python-2.7, graphics, pyqt, python-imaging-library

So far in my project I've tried both PIL (Image) and PyQt4. PIL seems to do too little for what I'm looking for, and PyQt4 seems to be too much, but they are almost all of what my searches have turned up so far.

I started with PIL, because I thought I only had to overlay .png files on top of each other and display them. The problem I encountered with that was that I was unable to close instances of opened images, and that was definitely not sustainable.

I moved into PyQt4, but now I'm having many issues that are becoming increasingly difficult to debug. For example, I'm getting input to the game from Twitch chat, but the GUI will crash when I try and call other functions, such as the one to get the Twitch chat input.

Is there a library I should be using that should be used for a game with graphical complexity somewhere in between PIL and PyQt? I'm just trying to display static .png files overlaid on each other with the ability to display the combined images easily and whenever I want (using time.sleep()'s, etc.).

Comment: **Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.**

Comment: Books and tutorials I understand.... but I see people suggesting certain tools and libraries as part of a solution all the time on this website!

Comment: You can suggest as a complement for answers, but it does not imply that the questions should ask for libraries, since each one will recommend the library that you like and you will mark as correct the one that you think is the best subjectively, without evidence, that's why those types of questions are currently not allowed, you already have 2 closing votes, another 3 and your question is closed. Read the following: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think I posed my question in a way which could be answered as objectively as any other question on this site is answered, and which I think could be very useful to others... but if these are the rules the community wants to follow, I understand.

Comment: In any case, I'm proceeding with PyGame!